# Toast notification not showing when button is clicked

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, notifications

I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.0 in VS2012.

I wanted to add a notification system for my app, so I searched for guides and found [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662938%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) from MDSN.

I used the same methods as those in the guide, but the notification doesn't appear when I click the button.

Here's the event handler method:

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ShellToast toast = new ShellToast();
    toast.Content = "Hello!";
    toast.Title = "StackOverFlow";
    toast.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use the native Toasts within your own app. These can be used via background tasks when you app is not running.

An alternative is using [Coding4Fun Toolkit](https://coding4fun.codeplex.com/) which has a ToastPrompt that can be used within the app.

Or if you don't want to get the whole Coding4Fun package, you can get [Toastinet](https://toastinet.codeplex.com/) instead.

Both are also available on Nuget.

Comment: I have Toolkit in my app , is the ToastPrompt a XAML element or you just set it in the code?

Comment: Just set it in code. ToastPrompt toast = new ToastPrompt(); and then you can set an ImageSource, Message, Title. Then just call toast.Show();